# Sourcing Layer in TOC to New Feature Class using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, layers, python-script-tool

I'm trying to source a layer in my TOC with a new feature class. I've read countless forums, ArcGIS Resource Center, etc. With the MXD and python window open this is what I've surmised so far.

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocumnet("CURRENT")
```

Using the following [link](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s30000004p000000.htm), which scenario matches what I want to do most accurately?

MXD Source = `r'\\na\data\telecom\projects\GIS\Proposal_Kentucky_Nextgen\02GISData\18DDP_ENG\MXDS\ENCHROACHMENT MXD\0180.SA - C001-C010 - 1.0 - PE.mxd`

MXD Name = `0180.SA - C001-C010 - 1.0 - PE.mxd`

Layer Name in TOC = `STRUCTURE_SITEID_180`

Layer in TOC's path = `\\na\data\telecom\projects\GIS\Proposal_Kentucky_Nextgen\02GISData\18DDP_ENG\Design_Data.gdb\STRUCTURE_SITEID_180`

Feature Class I Want to Source to Name = `STRUCTURE_SITEID_211`

Feature Class I Want to Source to File Path (same as the layer I'm trying to resource) = `\\na\data\telecom\projects\GIS\Proposal_Kentucky_Nextgen\02GISData\18DDP_ENG\Design_Data.gdb\STRUCTURE_SITEID_211`

How do I finish the Python script to accomplish the task? If I can get one to work I can extrapolate. I'm using ArcMap 10.3.1.

Comment: I've looked at it numerous times and I simply don't have the experience to extrapolate. Any sample script pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There will be a number of scripts on this site already that illustrate this.

Comment: I've deleted two of my comments above because I had forgotten that `dataSource` is a read-only property of a Layer object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation at [Updating and fixing data sources with arcpy.mapping](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/updatingandfixingdatasources.htm) says

> - findAndReplaceWorkspacePath or findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths allows you to substitute an entire or partial string for a layer or table's
>     workspace path. **It can't be used if the workspace type or dataset name
>     has changed**. It is ideal for scenarios where drive letters change,
>     switch to UNC paths, update SDE connection file information, and so
>     on. See the Common Scenarios section below.
> - replaceWorkspaces or replaceDataSource allows you to change the workspace path, workspace type, and / or **change the dataset name**.

(emphasis mine)

So in order to change the layer dataset source you will need to use `.replaceDataSource()`.

You will need to loop through your layers and use `layer.replaceDataSource()` to update the datasource and `layer.name` to update the layer name.

Something along the lines of the following:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
oldLayerName = 'STRUCTURE_SITEID_180' # Current name of the layer you wish to change
myGDB = r'\na\data\telecom\projects\GIS\Proposal_Kentucky_Nextgen\02GISData\18DDP_ENG\Design_Data.gdb' # Geodatabase that contains the new feature class
newFCName = 'STRUCTURE_SITEID_211'    # Name of the feature class in the GDB
newLayerName = 'STRUCTURE_SITEID_211' # Name of the layer in ArcMap TOC - doesn't need to be the same as the feature class name

for layer in layers:
    if layer.name == oldLayerName:
        layer.replaceDataSource(myGDB, "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE", newFCName)
        layer.name = newLayerName 
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

Comment: Extremely helpful Midavalo, I was initially getting an error but figured out the problem was a missing "\" for the geodatabase the contained the feature class.