# Replace Feature Class with Another Feature Class inside an .mxd

Tags: arcpy, feature-class, mxd

I am trying to create a script that makes a copy of the same feature class within the same file GDB by using the "copyfeatures" syntax which works fine.  I am then trying to iterate through a list of .mxd's within a certain directory and find any .mxd with the feature class that I made a copy of and replace that feature class with the newer version or the copy of that feature class that I created earlier in the script.

The scripts seems to be running with the syntax below, the .mxd's are being saved and the script runs with no problems.  However, the feature class in the .mxd is not updating.

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\GISShare\jehmann\TESTING.gdb"

workspace = r"C:\TEST"
outdata_1 = r"C:\GISShare\jehmann\TESTING.gdb\JeffNotes_SHLs"

# Copy New Version of the Feature Classes

try:
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('Notes_SHLs', 'JeffNotes_SHLs')
    print "SHLs Feature Class Created Succesfully!"
except:
    print "Failed to Create SHLs Feature Class"


for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, topdown=True):
    arcpy.env.workspace = dirpath
    mxds = arcpy.ListFiles('*.mxd')
    for filename in mxds:
        print "------------------------------"
        print filename
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
        for layer in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
            if layer.supports("DATASOURCE"):
                print "{} -> {}".format(layer.name, layer.dataSource)
                if '%Notes_SHLs%' in layer.dataSource:
                    layer.replaceDataSource(layer.dataSource, "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE", outdata_1)

        mxd.save()
```

I think it has something to do with how I have the layer.replaceDataSource set up?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: Does it print this line `print "{} -> {}".format(layer.name, layer.dataSource)`?

Comment: Does it actually enter the `if '%Notes_SHLs%' in layer.dataSource:` block?  Add a print inside that block to test

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include any clarification in response to comments

Comment: it does print the "{} -> {}".format(layer.name, layer.dataSource) line and lists all the layers in each .mxd.  When I add the print in the if '%Notes_SHLs%' in layer.dataSource: block it does not print anything?

Answer (score 1):

Take the two `%` out of this line `if '%Notes_SHLs%' in layer.dataSource:`

If you want to check if a specific string is within a variable, you need to exclude the `%` wildcard symbols

```
if 'Notes_SHLs' in layer.dataSource:
```

---

In response to your comment below, do a `print` on that `layer.dataSource` rather than the `if` to determine what is actually there:

```
if layer.supports("DATASOURCE"):
    print layer.dataSource
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, that is what I had tried initially and when I run it that way it is returning an "Unexpected Error"...not sure where to go from here?

Comment: @jaehmann where is the Unexpected Error occuring?  On the `if 'Notes_SHLs'...` line, or the one after?

Comment: It is occuring on the line after.  The 
    "layer.replaceDataSource(layer.dataSource, "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE", 
     outdata_1)"

Comment: Looking at a similar Q&A [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/231685/64785), try setting your `outdata_1` to just be the feature class name, not the entire path

Comment: That seemed to work!  I changed the outdata_1 to just be the feature class name not the entire path as well as instead of using "layer.dataSource" in the replaceDataSource line I plugged in the full path to the file GDB.

Comment: @jaehmann If this has worked for you, the way to say "thanks" here is to upvote and accept the answer.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)